# Is it possible to get a transit visa to Cambodia online or at the border town of Aranyaprathet?

Tags: visas, transit, cambodia, swedish-citizens

Is it possible to get a transit visa to Cambodia online or at the border town of Aranyaprathet?

Hello,

I will go to Phnom Penh next month. I have a Swedish passport.

Is it possible to get a transit visa to Cambodia online or at the border town of Aranyaprathet? (Please note: transit visa, not travel or tourist visa).

What documents do I need to prepare if it is indeed possible? What is the price?

Vesa

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you explain your specific need for a transit visa? Regular tourist visas are less restrictive, cheap and quickly issued on the spot.

Comment: Nope: it's very common for people to ask unclear or misguided questions here, and comments exist for the specific purpose of clarifying what exactly they're trying to accomplish.  So it sounds like your goal is to save a few bucks, and you're sure you're be out of Cambodia within 3 days?

Comment: The price difference is something like $8 USD. That being said, the official eVisa site has a discrete list of ports of entry which can be used with an eVisa, of which this town is not one.

Answer (score 4):

**Cambodia no longer offers a transit visa and you will have to apply for a standard [eVisa](https://www.evisa.gov.kh/) online, this will cost $36 (USD).**

From the [visa page](https://www.evisa.gov.kh/information/tourist_visa/4) the requirements are:

> Passport validity of more than six months balance at the time of entry, a recent passport-size photo in digital format (JPEG or PNG format), a valid credit card (Visa/MasterCard).

Additional details that the form asks for are:

- Name
- Email
- Telephone
- Email
- Date of birth
- Country of birth and nationality
- Address
- Address during visit
- Passport number, date of issue and expiry, country of issue
- Intended date of entry
- Port of entry

You won't be able to get a visa on arrival in Aranyaprathet as **tourist visas are available on arrival at Phnom Penh or Siem Reap international airports only** according to the [UK GOV website](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/cambodia/entry-requirements).